# How to fetch records from Json Placeholder, store it in an array and print on screen

Tags: angular, typescript, jsonplaceholder

I'm using Json placeholder. I want to learn how to fetch records from remote server and use it. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-photographs',
  templateUrl: './photographs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./photographs.component.css']
})
export class PhotographsComponent implements OnInit {

  myStringifiedJson;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.myStringifiedJson["title"]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this.myStringifiedJson=JSON.parse(json));
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.myStringifiedJson is undefined

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vxjfqk).
Please correct me. Do I have to use `stringify` here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple issues here

1. The variable `myStringifiedJson` is assigned asynchronously. So by the time you're console logging, it isn't assigned any value yet. Hence the `undefined` error in the console. You could find more info about async data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).
2. The value returned from the `response.json()` is already a valid JS object. The `JSON.parse()` isn't required.
3. The object returned from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos` is actually an array. So you can't access the property `title` directly. You could however use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to get all the titles as an array.

Try the following

```js
export class PhotographsComponent implements OnInit {
  myStringifiedJson: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.myStringifiedJson = json;
        console.log(this.myStringifiedJson.map(t => t['title']));    // <-- print here
      });
  }
}
```

I've updated your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tyxzfe?file=src/app/photographs/photographs.component.ts)

---

That said I'd recommend you to use Angular's [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) to make HTTP requests instead of `fetch`. It works in tandem with RxJS observables and provides many advantages like combining the response with RxJS operators and functions.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**photographs.component.ts**

```js
export class PhotographsComponent implements OnInit {
  myStringifiedJson: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').subscribe(
      response => {
        this.myStringifiedJson = response;
        console.log(this.myStringifiedJson.map(t => t['title']));
      },
      error => { console.log(error); }
    );
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vo1cr9?file=src/app/photographs/photographs.component.ts)

### Update: use `*ngFor`

You need to bind a variable before you could use the `index` local variable. Also each element of the array is an object, so without the [`json`](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) pipe it'd just render `[object Object]`.

```html
<p *ngFor="let item of myStringifiedJson">
  {{ item | json }}
</p>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-epfbfh?file=src/app/photographs/photographs.component.html)

Comment: Why did you inject `HttpClient` ? I'm asking this because I don't know. Any specific reason or it's just a good practice?

Comment: @Tanzeel: That's the standard procedure to use `HttpClient`. It's an [injectable class](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/10.1.3/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L99) decorated with `@Injectable`.

Comment: @Tanzeel: You need to bind a variable before you could use the `index` local variable. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I have great respect for people who not only answer the question but explain the solution also. I owe a lot to these kind of people. Wish I could learn more and more. Thanks a lot Michael. :-)